# Baixando a bibliotecas pelo MAVEN com proxy

Tags: demoiselle

Instalei a nova versão do demoiselle, mas ao gerar um projeto com o arquétipo `demoiselle-jsf-jpa` o projeto é gerado com erro e não consigo fazer o deploy.

Creio eu que seja devido ao proxy da rede, tanto é que exclui a pasta `/opt/demoiselle/tool/maven-repo/org`
e executei o `maven update project` e não baixou as dependências.

Alguém sabe me dizer quais os link para serem liberados no proxy para que o Maven consiga baixar as bibliotecas?

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional que está usando?

Answer (score 2):

São esses os endereços dos repositórios:

http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/

https://repository.jboss.org/

http://repository.primefaces.org

Comment: Estou usando o SO :  DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"

Comment: Saito, então são esses os repositórios para liberação? blz, vou ver se consigo liberar.. valeu, obrigado.

Comment: Certo Welder. Procure também utilizar a versão mais recente (caso não esteja: Demoiselle-2-Infra-4 já disponível para linux.

Answer (score 2):

Welder,

Não sei se ainda dá tempo de ajudar mas fica o registro, também tive problemas para baixar as bibliotecas por conta do proxy da rede. Não conseguia baixar pelo eclipse nem direto pelo Maven.

No meu caso eu precisei apenas configurar o Maven para acessar o proxy. A configuração do proxy fica no arquivo `C:\Demoiselle\tool\maven3-local-repo\settings.xml`, dentro deste arquivo adicionei as seguintes entradas:

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>endereço do proxy</host>
      <port>porta do proxy</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Feito isso passou a funcionar corretamente no Eclipse e no Maven.

Comment: Observe ainda que as vezes o Eclipse cria um arquivo Settings.xml próprio para seu uso, você pode ver este arquivo em: Window > Preference > Maven : User settings